# Application Chinese Remainder Theorem to Dedekind Domains

Tags: commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

I have a question about the application of CRT in a proof of following thread:
[Dedekind domain with a finite number of prime ideals is principal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95789/dedekind-domain-with-a-finite-number-of-prime-ideals-is-principal)

The claim is that a Dedekind domain with a finite number of prime ideals is already principal:

In his answer @pki uses following argument:

Let $R$ be a Dedekind ring and assume that the prime ideals are $\mathfrak{p}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{p}_n$. Then $\mathfrak{p}_1^2,\mathfrak{p}_2,\ldots,\mathfrak{p}_n$ are coprime. Pick an element $\pi \in \mathfrak{p}_1\setminus \mathfrak{p}_1^2$ and by CRT you can find an $x\in R$ s.t.

$$ x\equiv \pi\,(\textrm{mod } \mathfrak{p}_1^2),\;\; x\equiv 1\,(\textrm{mod } \mathfrak{p}_k),\; k=2,\ldots,n $$

Factoring we must have $(x)=\mathfrak{p}_1$ (???)

Indeed the CRT provides a $x$ such that $ x\equiv \pi\,(\textrm{mod } \mathfrak{p}_1^2),\;\; x\equiv 1\,(\textrm{mod } \mathfrak{p}_k),\; k=2,\ldots,n $ holds.

But why we get $(x)=\mathfrak{p}_1$?

Factoring just implies $(\bar{x}) = \mathfrak{p}_1/ \mathfrak{p}_1^2$. How to deduce $(x)=\mathfrak{p}_1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First $\newcommand{\pp}{\mathfrak{p}}\newcommand{\mm}{\mathfrak{m}}(x)=\pp_1^{e_1}\cdots \pp_n^{e_n}$ for some $e_i\in\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb{N}}\NN$. If $e_i \ge 1$ for $i\ge 2$, then $x\in(x)\subset \pp_i$, however, $x\equiv 1 \pmod{\pp_i}$, so this is impossible. Hence $(x)=\pp_1^{e_1}$, for some $e_1\ge 1$ (since $(x)\subset \pp_1$ by assumption, so $(x)\ne (1)$). However, $x\not\in \pp_1^2$ either, so $x\in(x)=\pp_1^{e_1}$ forces $e_1=1$. Thus $(x)=\pp_1$ as desired.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. One step stays unclear: How do you get $\newcommand{\pp}{\mathfrak{p}}\newcommand{\mm}{\mathfrak{m}}(x)=\pp_1^{e_1}\cdots \pp_n^{e_n}$?

Comment: @KarlPeter Ah, that's a definition of Dedekind domain, every nonzero ideal factors into primes. See Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain#Alternative_definitions

Comment: @KarlPeter For a proof you'll want to look at a resource on algebraic number theory, e.g. Milne's course notes here: http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ant.html

It's a little too involved for an answer here.