# $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[\zeta]$ principal ideal domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ denote the ring of rational p-adic integers (p prime), and let $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}$ be a root of unity of order $p \cdot m$, where $m$ is not divisible by $p$. Then apparently, the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[\zeta]$ is a principal ideal domain.

In [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256067890), the above statement is used implicitly, as if it was true for trivial reasons.

Does somebody know the reason why this is true? Does the statement become wrong if $\zeta$ is an arbitrary root of unity? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the case $m=1$ would go approximately as follows. Let $I\subset R=\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}[\zeta]$ be an arbitrary proper ideal. Then $\tilde{I}=I\cap\Bbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is a product of prime ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta]$. Let $\mathfrak{q}$ be one of those prime ideals, lying above the rational prime $q$. If $p\neq q$, then there are elements of $\mathfrak{q}$ with norms coprime to $p$, i.e. units of $R$, so in $R$ the ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ becomes trivial. Therefore only the case $q=p$ is interesting. But, in $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta]$ we have the factorization of ideal $(p)=(1-\zeta)^{p-1}$.

Comment: (cont'd) So it looks like all the ideals of $R$ should be powers of $(1-\zeta)$. Several unclear points. And an argument for $m>1$ is missing. I suspect we may be able to $\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta)$, but I don't have the time to think about this (and its anything but clear to me how we should proceed).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks a lot for sharing your thoughts! Do you think there is any chance that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[\zeta]$ is simply the intersection of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ and of the valuation ring of $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta)$ (and thus is a discrete valuation ring)?

Comment: Probably not. The $m$th cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_m(x)$ factors non-trivially modulo $p$ and hence also over $\Bbb{Q}_p$ by Hensel. So there should be several ideals "above" the rational prime $p$. Sounds more like the "non-principality" disappears when rational primes other than $p$ become units. I don't see a path though.

Comment: It is useful to [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) for the question. Maybe your comment about a paper which uses this would be better visible as a part of the question. (And it would also contribute to adding the context.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The useful fact here is that a Dedekind domain with only finitely many primes is a PID. See, for instance, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95789/dedekind-domain-with-a-finite-number-of-prime-ideals-is-principal). The proof is so simple that I’m abashed not to have seen it.

Anyhow, your ring has only the ideals above $(p)$.