# Number of maximal ideals of a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

Let $t \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $p_1,p_2,..., p_t$ be $t$ distinct prime numbers. Show that

$R=\{a\in \mathbb{Q} : a=\frac{m}{n} $ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n$ is divisible by none of $p_1,...., p_t \}$

is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ which has exactly $t$ maximal ideals.

I have easily shown $R$ is subring, but did not find the number of maximal ideals.

Comment: For an ideal $I$ of $R$ then $I \cap \Bbb{Z}$ is an ideal of $\Bbb{Z}$, there are not so many of them. Can you show from this what are the ideals of $R$ when $t = 1$ ?

Comment: @reuns why "there are not so many of them "?

Comment: In $\Bbb{Z}$ it is easily shown $(u,v) = (w)$ (where $w = \gcd(u,v)$) so every ideal is principal. Can you show $I = R\ ( I \cap \Bbb{Z})$ ? Thus what can be $I \cap \Bbb{Z},I$ ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the theory of localizations? Your ring is the locations of $\mathbb{Z}$ away from $p_1,\ldots,p_t$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin no

Answer (score 2):

Localization answer: Set $P_i:=\langle p_i\rangle$ for each $i$ ( the ideal generated by $p_i$ in $\mathbb{Z}$) and set $S:=\mathbb{Z}\setminus\bigcup_iP_i$. Clearly $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $R=\{a\in \mathbb{Q} : a=\frac{m}{n} $ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n$ is divisible by none of $p_1,...., p_t \}=S^{-1}\mathbb Z$.

Now since $\mathrm{Spec}(S^{-1}\mathbb{Z})=\{S^{-1}P\mid P\bigcap S=\varnothing\}\bigcup\{0\}=\{S^{-1}P_1,..., S^{-1}P_t\}\bigcup\{0\}$, we have $\mathrm{Max}(S^{-1}\mathbb{Z})=\{S^{-1}P\mid P\bigcap S=\varnothing\}=\{S^{-1}P_1,..., S^{-1}P_t\}$.

Another elementary answer: For each $i$, set $Q_i:=\{a\in \mathbb{Q} : a=\frac{m}{n} $ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}\text{ and } n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ n$ is divisible by none of $p_1,...., p_t$ and  $p_i$ divides $ m\}$. An easy argument shows that $Q_i$'s are distinct maximal ideals of $R$ and every proper ideal of $R$ is contained in one of them. Hence, $\mathrm{Max}(R)=\{Q_1,..., Q_t\}.$

Comment: Can anyone verify wheather R is a PID or not ?

Comment: @PritamRoy [any Dedekind domain with finitely many maximal ideals is a PID](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95789/dedekind-domain-with-a-finite-number-of-prime-ideals-is-principal).